# Where to start rtk and Rinex?

Tags: real-time, rinex

I am totally new at this field and I want to use Rinex data to add more precision to my GPS receiver.

I don't know where to start and even I spend a lot of time googling, I just got more confused.

Can anyone help me with a starting point?

I want to determine the exact 3D position of a flying quadrotor while flying (So i need the position realtime).

The main project is multi-agent UAV flying, so their position has to be accurate enough to prevent crashing during flight. Also for accurate landing in a desired position.

In the first phase I need to know position relative to a ground station in a not so far distance (I mean about 5-7 meter from robot). And this station (the positioning reference) doesn't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a UAV research project, you may want to take a look at the [Canberra UAV pyUBlox real time corrections](https://github.com/tridge/pyUblox/) project. That is open source, so you can see what is happening and tweak it to suit your needs.

There was a [recent talk](http://lca2014.linux.org.au/schedule/30165/view_talk) about this at linux.conf.au. Video is [available](http://mirror.linux.org.au/linux.conf.au/2014/Wednesday/45-Building_an_affordable_differential_GPS_positioning_system_-_Andrew_Tridgell,_Ben_Nizette.mp4).

Also check the [wikipedia page for RTK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Kinematic) if you haven't see this already.